# Encountered an issue when attempting to copy shape keys from a previously created model

Tags: shape-keys

I have recently created a 3D model in Blender and am currently working on implementing lip sync using shape keys. In the process, I encountered an issue when attempting to copy shape keys from a previously created model. The error message indicates a mismatch in vertex count.
To address this, I tried using the ShapeKeysTransfer add-on. While it successfully transfers the shape keys , they are not mapped with the destination mesh's face.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance you could provide in resolving this matter.